# Invalid JSON, 400 Bad request in Angular $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, postgresql, http

This is my data object -

```js
var bill = {
                 "type":"insert",
                 "args": {
                    "table": "finance_data",
                    "objects": [
                    {
                      "title": $scope.data.title,
                      "url": $scope.data.url,
                      "type":"payments"
                    }
                  ]
                }
            };
```

This is my config object-

```js
var config = {
                  headers:{
                    'Authorization' : "Bearer "+ $localStorage.auth_token,
                }
             };
```

I'm doing a POST request to my server to insert data into a table ( db: PostgreSQL)
This is my http request code-

```js
$http.post('https://data.saarang.org/v1/query', bill, config).then(function(response){
                console.log('success');
                alert('Successfully uploaded the Payment Receipt!');
                $state.reload();
             }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
```

This is the err object -

```js
Object { data: Object, status: 400, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "Bad Request" }
```

The err.data object has an error message - 'invalid JSON'
The bill object has all the fields that are required but still the server throws back an "invalid JSON" error
Please Help !

Comment: are you sure that `$scope.data.title` and `$scope.data.url` both return values?

Comment: Yes...i have also tried replacing those two variables with double quoted strings...but still I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Robin: check once again what exactly your api needs. Its very clear that you are not sending data in the format which your api accepts. It will be better if you can provide that info too, that will be easier to help u.

Comment: Does your backend (script) generate this Error, or the server itself? Does the data even reach your backend script? Have you checked the request in the network-tab of your dev-tools? Maybe down to the raw request. Is the path and method correct? The POST body, the request header, ...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself, it wasn't any backend/server related issue, the **url** key in the object was supposed to be **Url**. The typo caused an invalid JSON error.